# Opening files, writing, to files, and deleting from files in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have an assignment where I have a constructor, and two methods. The constructor opens the file, and if the file doesn't exist, it creates one. The methods merely add a new line to the file and delete a specific line from the file. I have this :

```
public openFile(String fileName) {
    File f = new File(filename);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    if (f.exists()) {
        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            if (b.readLine().contains(COMMA)) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA); // parse information on line
                User u = new User(tokens[0], tokens[1]); // Creates new user
            } else {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            b.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My other methods are:

```
public add(String[] args) {
   FileWriter fileWriter;
   BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
   String message = args[1] + COMMA + args[2] + "\n";
   try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(TEST_CSV, true); // Test_CSV is name of the file I have to write to.
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(message);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            //Do nothing
    }
```

But it simply doesn't work. How could I change it so that it would add the file without deleting it and creating a new file every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `f.createNewFile();` was in the wrong place, it was executing each time you read a line from the file, try this:

```
public openFile(String fileName) {
    File f = new File(filename);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    if (f.exists()) {
        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            if (b.readLine().contains(COMMA)) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA); // parse information on line
                User u = new User(tokens[0], tokens[1]); // Creates new user
            }
        }

    } else {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    b.close();
}
```

Also, you were closing the buffered reader after every line also so i moved `b.close();`